# Correlation analysis with compound variables: controling for a second correlation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, partial-correlation, controlling-for-a-variable

We want to test for the existence of a correlation between a variable $X$ and a second variable $Y=ab$ ($a$ and $b$ being independent variables representing observational data). We know that the variable $X$ is correlated with the variable $Z=ac$ ($a$ as described above, and $c$ a different independent variable, representing observational data as well). How can one test for the presence of the $X vs Y$  correlation while accounting and controlling for the presence of $X vs Z$ (which one considers to have been secured)?

As a subsidiary question, should the correlation testing be done simultaneously, or can be done independently?

Comment: The answer to "How can one test for the presence of the X vs Y correlation while accounting and controlling for the presence of X vs Z" is to perform a multiple regression of $X$ against $Y$ and $Z$. Could you explain why any of the other information you have provided would indicate that is still not the right answer?  For instance, do you know the values of $a$, $b$, and $c$ as well as those of $Y$ and $Z$? What is the importance of describing the problem in terms of $b$ and $c$ rather than more simply in terms of $b^n$ and $c^m$? Could any of these values ever be negative?

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I understand a multiple regression of $X(Y,Z)$ would be the best way if one is sure about both correlations, but we want to test the correlation between $X$ and $Y$. Is it still correct on this case. Yes, we do know the values of $a$,$b$, $c$, $n$, and $m$ (and as such $Y$ and $Z$). I will remove the mention to the exponents, as it only complicates the description without providing further information.